# Button displaying white canvas instead of image

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create an image, but it's not working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. All I get when I click the button that should display the image is the white canvas, without the image. How do I get it to display?

```
def show_original(self):

    from os.path import exists
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk


    if not os.path.exists(self.wdg_orig_file_name_.get()):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('Load','File does not exist:' + self.wdg_orig_file_name_.get())

        return
    self.orig_image_=Image.open(str_orig_file_name)
    canvas = self.gui_.ca(500,500,bg='white')
    im_TK = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.orig_image_)
    canvas.create_image(250,250,image=im_TK)
    canvas.pack()
    pass
```

`self.wdg_orig_file_name_.get()` in the main loop is:

```
 self.wdg_orig_file_name_ = self.gui_.en(text='boat.png')
```

The global `str_orig_file_name` is assigned in `pick_file()`:

```
def pick_file(self):
    '''Opens a file dialog and sets its result to the filename entry'''
    global str_orig_file_name
    str_orig_file_name = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if str_orig_file_name:
        self.wdg_orig_file_name_.delete(0, END)
        self.wdg_orig_file_name_.insert(0, str_orig_file_name)

        #We got a new image to process. Forget the previous results.
        self.orig_image_ = None
        self.preview_image_ = None
```

Comment: So what is your question? Do you get an error? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry. i edited my question.

Comment: It looks like you're already using `tkinter` as your GUI toolkit, correct? And have you tried saving the final `PhotoImage` object `im_TK` as `self.im_TK` instead, so that the reference doesn't get garbage-collected?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm a Python beginner and to be honest I'm not sure if I imported the right libs. I thought PIL is the one I need here, but according to your comment I tried to `import tkinter` and got error which I have `no moudle name tkinter`. it's probably it. now I guess my next question should be "how do I install tkinter in Portable Python" :(

Comment: Well, if it's running Python 2, then you need to `import Tkinter` with a capital `T`. If it just plain doesn't include any flavor of `tkinter`, you're in for some fun (I still haven't figured out how to do it on my Ubuntu live USB setup).

Comment: you right. `import Tkinter` with capital letter worked. I feel so noob. now I'm confused.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried easygui?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from easygui import *

image = "img.jpg"
msg   = "Do you like this picture?"
choices = ["Yes","No","No opinion"]
reply=buttonbox(msg,image=image,choices=choices)
```

Very easy.

http://www.ferg.org/easygui/tutorial.html

Comment: The OP didn't clearly specify it, but it looks like they're using `tkinter` widgets and functions, so I don't think they're looking for GUI recommendations (which would be off-topic anyway).

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry. I though the OP was looking for a way to display an image and now I see the image is supposed to be on the button. Well I tried this and it works just fine with .gif and .png. However .jpg gives an error: "_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "img.jpg"".

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
b=Button(root,justify = LEFT)
photo=PhotoImage(file="img.png")
b.config(image=photo,width="100",height="100")
b.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```